# c++ organising variables for computation - speed and readability

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, containers

I'm currently doing large numerical computations and speed is of utmost importance when using variables (of type double).  want to know if there is a more readable way to do the following or if there is a more better way using structs or boost libraries.

**UPDATE: after some though, my initial aim due to many variables, is to organise the variables indirectly into some sort of container preferably while maintaining the variables as objects and not references/pointers.**

**1) I will be doing large and lengthy computations on the variables, they're declared in the order they are used and changing throughout the program**

**2) Variables can be added to the program at any time when I decide to edit the code (quite frequent)**

**3) Organizing variables (into a container of pointers or whatever) is important for ease of working with these objects collectively - it will be much more streamlined and efficient code when I e.g. write to file all these objects after some time**

**I was thinking to instead make a class that create a type (All the variable objects are of type double) and automatically adds to a vector of pointers - as a side question, would this be an overkill**

I have many variables doing all sorts of computations like so (which happen to take time):

```
double varName1 = someValue;
double varName2 = someValue;
double varName3 = someValue;
...
double varNameN = someValue;
...
SOME_COMPUTATION HERE
```

This is I believe most obvious way for readability of each variable. To store the collection for possible output in the future, I put everything into a container, and made a reference variable to each element like so

```
std::vector<double> store;
...
ADD VALUES TO VECTOR
...
double& varName1 = store[0];
double& varName2 = store[1];
...
```

When I do the above method however, computation with reference (&) variables is more costly (overtime). Then i decided to do the opposite, store a vector of pointers instead to the variables, if i need to write all files to file for example i'll use this vector and perform computation on the variables as normal (not references). To do this I came up with the following (ugly) way

```
std::vector<double*> store;
double create_v(double init, double& d)
{
    store.push_back(&d);
    d = init;
}

double varName1 = create_v(0.05,varName1);
```

I was wandering if 1) there is a better implementation of this using templates/boost for readability that does the same thing OR 2) Is there another way a C++ beginner like me should know? 3) optimizations I'm not considering that minimize some overhead mentioned above (I test with -O2 and -O3 and I use g++4.7.2)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Tight optimization almost always required specific knowledge of the circumstances.  I won't say for sure that any one method is faster for what you need to do than others, but I will say that avoiding pointers and references might help.  Furthermore, in order to benefit from cache locality, try to declare things in the order they're used.

Comment: @Wug Thanks for your comment. I updated the above for clarity which has more information, new parts are in bold

Answer (score 1):

The 4.7.2 version of g++ provides [support](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html) of C++11's [*initializer lists*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm). This means that you can write the following code to put all your variables in a `vector<double>`:

```
vector<double> vec = {varName1, varName2, varName3, ..., varNameN};
```

This is reasonably clean, and should provide you with a simple way of organizing your variables into a vector for the output purposes. Here is a [small demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/zEcP5v).

P.S. Your third example does not work, because you are pushing back a reference, rather than a pointer. This should be a compile-time error, though.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I provided more clarity in the above question in bold for my needs. Note that varName1 etc are changing values (important point missed, sorry :( ) and objects are declared in varied positions before they are used. I would think I need them that way since I noticed a difference in speed otherwise. These computations will be long (days) and purely for numerical analysis

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it might be acceptable to use a c-style struct.  You can take advantage of certain behavior of structs that meet certain restrictions (Plain Old Data restrictions, or POD) that further simplify their behavior.

POD structs can't have a default constructor, destructor, or copy constructor (other than the defaults provided by the compiler), and can't have any virtual methods or any members of pointer or reference types.  You should be able to accomplish this without much difficulty.

Once you've done that, you'll be able to declare such a struct like this:

```
struct DataSet
{
    double foo;
    double bar[48]; // arrays are legal in POD types
    // snip however many more declarations
};
```

You will be able to save these structures to a file with something like:

```
DataSet ds;
// populate and process dataset
ofstream outputfile("somefile.dat", ios_base::out);
outputfile.write((char *) &ds, sizeof(DataSet));
```

Reading them would work exactly as you expect: the opposite of writing.  Just create the object and slurp the contents of the file into it.  Working with an array of `DataSet` should be equally intuitive.

Comment: It is very important to note however that this method will offer very little version safety.  Consider adding a scheme to verify that the data you read from a file is of the version you expect.  Since the contents of the file will literally be the binary data of the struct, reordering members or adding/removing members will, put colloquially, screw up everything.